# Protobuf how to receive string and object multiple times

Tags: java, c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am using a server and a client. The client only should deserialize the received protobuf message if the string "yes" is received.

EDIT:

The first message of protobuf is received well. But, if I want to send multiple messages at a time, it gives me:

> System.OverflowException: Number overflow.
>     at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.TryReadUInt32Variant (System.IO.Stream source, System.UInt32& value)

I read through this link, but I can't figured out what I should do in my case...

I am using TCP sockets. Here is an example code:

Client C#:

```
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(host, port);
NetworkStream netStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(netStream);

while(true)
{
    // Read multiple messages one after another.
    string message = reader.ReadLine();
    if(message.Equals("yes"))
    {
        Command command = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<Command>    (netStream, PrexiStyle.Base128);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.Create));
        bw.Write(command.File);
        bw.Flush();
        bw.Close();
    }
}
```

Server Java:

```
OutputStream outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outputStream, true);
try{
    // send "yes" and the protobuf messages ten times one after another
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        writer.println("yes");
        command.writeDelimitedTo(outputStream);
    }
}catch(Exception e)
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
    outputStream.close();
    clientSocket.close();
}
```

My .proto file and proto contract has the same types. It works if I don't want to send a string, but only the protobuf message.

How can I solve this with using a string before deserializing the protobuf message? Is it possible?

Comment: Look at my answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810153/send-binary-file-from-java-server-to-c-sharp-unity3d-client-with-protocol-buffer/32845881#32845881) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32182035/set-maximum-size-of-protobuf-object/32198789#32198789).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, you said in the first answered question that the function "writeDelimitedTo" do exactly write the size and then send the message itself. So, in C# I read the delimited message with "DeserializeWithLengthPrefix". But, before I send a protobuf message, I have to send a string. So, how can I achieve that? I thought that protobuf writes and reads the size with these mentioned functions...but it seemingly isn't the right way.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? Is reader the same as netStream? `yes` is your own delimiter, do you need this, is the socket used for other communication than protobuf? Also try to print the whole buffer on both ends and compare it with what `DeserializeWithLengthPrefix` is trying to deserialize.

Comment: @petersv I edited my question and added more necessary code. The reader reads from the netStream, yes. Yes, I need to differentiate between  a protobuf message and a message with simple datatypes.

Comment: Are `tcpClient` and `client`the same?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. There was two typos in my edit. `tcpClient` and `clientSocket.close();`.

Comment: `netStream` and `reader` are both receiving the socket data (not necessary the same data?), I don't think that you can do it that way. I don't know how they consume data, but using one reader instead would be my guess.

Comment: So you mean, I should read in directly from `netStream` like this way: `netStream.Read(...);` instead of my way with the `ReadLine()` method?

Comment: My guess is that `ReadLine` does in fact read a line, looking for delimiter like endline etc. That means that when you get 'yes' it has also consumed the protobuf msg.

Comment: Indeed, it makes sense. Thanks for that. But how can I solve this problem? I can't just add a newline between "yes" and "protobuf message" to delimit them. My idea is that I should write the length of the string, then the string itself and serialize the protobuf message and on the other side, read the length and then the string. If it is the string "yes" then try to deserialize protobuf message. So in this case I would choose `print()` and `Read()` instead of `println()` and `ReadLine()`. Is this possible or is it a terrible idea?

Comment: As I mentioned briefly earlier, I would rather use a separate TCP socket for protobuf, and send all the other data on another socket. Then your code should work, if you remove the "if(yes)"-part.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Is it possible that you provide me a simple example how to do that? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I posted an answer below with some example code. While looking at the code, I noticed a few things. You exsisting code mught work if you just add the while loop around the receiving part, since you write "yes" with `println`. Anyway I would just skip the yes part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try separating protobuf data and other data in different sockets. Added a while loop to be able to read multiple messages from server.

```
using System.Threading;
new Thread(() => 
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true; 
    // Protobuf data is read on this socket
    TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(host, port);
    NetworkStream netStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(netStream);

    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.Create));
    bool running = true;
    while(running)
    {
        bw.Write(Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<Command>(netStream, PrexiStyle.Base128).File);
    }
    bw.Flush();
    bw.Close();
}).Start();

// Other data is read no this socket
TcpClient tcpClientForOtherStuff = new TcpClient(host, port);
NetworkStream netStream = tcpClientForOtherStuff.GetStream();
StreamReader readerForOtherStuff = new StreamReader(netStream);
string message;
bool running = true;
BinaryWriter bwForOtherStuff = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(path2, FileMode.Create));
bool running = true;
while(running) bwForOtherStuff.Write(readerForOtherStuff.ReadLine());
bwForOtherStuff.Flush();
bwForOtherStuff.Close();
```

I have not tested or compiled the code.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer and your time! However, I know that the protobuf message works without sending a string as I noted in my question "_It works if I don't want to send a string, but only the protobuf message._" Sorry for this misunderstanding. My problem is, that I need to send simple string messages and protobuf messages and need to differentiate them. Your Idea with two separate sockets will surely work. But my problem is, how to realize that. Do I need parallel threads on server and client to establish connection on two sockets at the same time? I think so, because of blocking.

Comment: Hi, see my edit. I added a while loop to your initial code, as explained in my last comment.

Comment: Hi, thanks again. I tried it, but it is still not working. I get another error message as you can see in my edited question. If I printed `message` after  `reader.ReadLine()`, the first message which is sent, tell me `yes` but the second say `yes` and some weird characters. So, I assume as you already said before the protobuf message is consumed from `reader.ReadLine()`..

Comment: Then you can use two readers, as my new edit. Or you can parse the original stream manually, read (not readline) all the data and buffer it, look for "yes" and then send the following protobuf data to the protobuf deserializer. My example that I posted a link to earlier does this, except the "yes" part.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and patience! It works perfectly. :)